# Which JavaScript AJAX Framework is most powerful and very lightweight?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, frameworks

I've been using jQuery to do the whole AJAX magic in my web based applications.
But I came to a decision that I don’t need all these amazing features jQuery has, except its AJAX functions (like `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post`, `getJSON()` and `load();`).

Can you recommend a lightweight crossbrowser AJAX library/framework (up to ~10 kb)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make jQuery smaller by removing the modules you don't need / Just modify the [Makefile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile) file.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use ONLY ajax features take a look at [sajax](http://www.modernmethod.com/sajax/index.phtml) or custom [MooTools](http://mootools.net). Of course, if you are a "lightweight freak" you can write your own routine for this (should be less than 50 lines)

Comment: @ Staicu Ionut, thanks. I've just tried to build a MooTools based one, but it's still too big. Sajax is a server-side based one, in my case it's not that I want ajax framework to be. I've found jx, which is a very lightweight one and seems it supports json. Need to look.

Answer (score 1):

MochiKit might fit your needs: http://mochikit.com/

Although lightweight and powerful it might not meet the 10kb requirement (you can trim it down to only the async module)

The equivalent methods would be:

- doXHR
- doSimpleXMLHttpRequest
- evalJSONRequest
- loadJSONDoc
- sendXMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

Really lightweight there is SACK (Simple AJAX Code Kit)
I don't use myself but it looks really simple

edit : I checked, the js file is about 5kB

Answer (score 0):

*MooTools*...!!

Don't believe the jQuery guys ... ;)